# Python string exact end, no additional characters

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to replace a string element, but only if it doesn't have additional characters after the match, though the characters before the match can vary...  For example, if I tokenize a name containing underscores, and I want to replace anything that ends with "R", but not elements that start with it... so it would replace "R", or "SideR", but not "Rear" because there are characters that follow after "R". I remember someone showing me something like this before, but can't find it. It was something akin to \n (but wasn't \n, which is a new line, there is no new line), but could be put at the end of a string to denote no further characters (There was ether one for the start... may have been the same thing for start or end).

```
test="New_R_SideR_Rear_Object"
tokens=test.split("_")
newtest=""
for each in tokens:
    if "R" in each:
        each=each.replace("R", "L")
    newtest=(newtest+each+"_")
```

I'm positive there is something I can add to the end of the "if "R" in each" line, or the .replace line, that will allow me to ensure that "Rear" doesn't become "Lear", but both "R" and "SideR" doe get replaced.

The above is just simplified for ease of explanation. Thanks for your time

Comment: Regular expressions. You're looking for regular expressions.

Comment: why dont you just do `test = "New_R_SideR_Rear_Object".replace('R_','L_')`

Comment: Have a look at Regular Expressions (re module) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.  The regular expression language provides a compact way to express how to match text.  For your example:

```
$ python3
>>> import re
>>> test="New_R_SideR_Rear_Object"
>>> re.sub(r"R(_|\b)", r"L\1", test)
'New_L_SideL_Rear_Object'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into regular expressions. Not entirely sure it's what I'm looking for, but might be. My intention was for more than just replace (should have mentioned that... sometimes I get too specific)... being able to do "if X in Y:" comparisons with the same criteria is also part of what I need this for... but that looks like it might be included. I'll follow up once I've read up more on the expressions

Comment: Yup. re.search in the if statement, with \b, gets what I'm looking for. Thank you.